# Prevent NaN's from being entered into a contenteditable field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, jquery-events

I'm looking for a way to make a numeric-only (or extensively, something that would work with multiple types of validators on the fly) so far I have something like:

```
this.ContentEditable.bind("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if ((event.data.NumericOnly === true) && (event.which != 8) && (event.which != 189) && (event.which != 190)) {
        var c = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        if ('0123456789'.indexOf(c) < 0) { return (false); }
    }
});
```

The caveat with this method being that if a user has already typed a "." (character 190, `String.fromCharCode` doesn't work with it, character 8 is backspace) or a "-" (character 189) is duplicated and/or anywhere but the first character in the `contenteditable=true`'s text it should be viewed as invalid.  I could get the text and cancel the input with return (false); if it already contains a "." and a "." is being typed or check if the cursor is at position zero for a "-" with none already existing in the `contenteditable=true`'s text, but I'd like something more extensible.

Is it possible to get the final result of the key event so I can send it off to a validator while I still have the option to cancel the key event?

Comment: I'd personally do it in the lazy way - every time the user inputs something (`.on('input', fn)` for modern browsers) try to evaluate it to a number, if it fails restore to the previous value (possibly through some `.data()` hackery if `event.preventDefault()` doesn't do it).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The problem there being that the cursor position gets screwed up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did a patch for that which saves the `element.selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` and takes in consideration how many characters were removed before the `selectionStart` before setting it back, and the chars removed before `selectionEnd` before setting it back as well. Mine is a little too ugly as when I tested, Chrome fired the `input` event before moving the cursor while Firefox does it after, which requires some hackery to get a nice cross-browser behavior. And I didn't even attempt to make it work on old IE.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: LOL! Sounds like a lot of "fun." :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes it was. `;)` basically, I used a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` inside the `input` handler so that both browsers would have moved the cursor to after the inputted character(s). I'll make a repo for it if I ever get it working in IE8 (well, up to IE10's `input` and `propertychanged` events do not fire for backspace/erased characters so the behavior would still be inconsistent..)

Comment: Don't forget that a keydown handler isn't enough to enforce valid values, because the user can change the field with cut or paste or drag'n'drop.